# How to formularize the total number of subsets of a set where some elements may be chosen from a finite list?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Consider the following example:

The set $A = \{1,\{a,b,c,d\},\{e,f\},5,7,11,13,17,19\}$, where the second and third elements represent the sets of choices for the second and third elements. We could write, $A = \{1,\{|4|\},\{|2|\},5,7,11,13,17,19\}$

Then the total number of subsets for $A$ would be $2^9 + 4*2^8 + 3*2^7$. I found this by writing out the different choices for $A$ and considering which subsets would have already been counted after the initial $2^n$, where $n = |A|$:

# subsets for $\{1,a,e,5,7,11,13,17,19\} = 2^9$
$+$
# subsets for $\{1,b,e,5,7,11,13,17,19\} = 2^8$

...

Can and how may this be formularized for an arbitrary number and size of "choice-type" elements in $A$?

Comment: "the second and third elements represent the sets of choices for the second and third elements"?

Comment: @JackM Thank you for your comment. What I mean is, given `A = {1,{2,3},4}`, `A` could be `{1,2,4}` or `{1,3,4}` but `2` and `3` cannot be together in any one subset of the total subsets for `A`. Is there a better/clearer way to describe the second and third elements in my example?

Comment: So what you're saying is, you want to define a notion of "pseudo subset" such that a pseudo subset of $A$ is a set of elements of $A$ and at most one element from each set that is a member of $A$.

Comment: @JackM Yes, that makes sense, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what you mean by "formalize". Your definition is a little muddled, so I suppose stating it in more precise language could be helpful.

Here's how I would express what you're trying to say:

- A *menu* is a family of sets.

You may think that not every element of a menu has to be a set, some of the elements might be numbers. For instance, you might have something like $\{1, 2, \{a ,b\}\}$. But this is equivalent to $\{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{a ,b\}\}$.

- If $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ is a menu and $J\subseteq I$, then let $\phi:J\to \bigcup_{j\in J} A_j$ be a function such that $(\forall j\in J)\ \phi(j)\in A_j$. Then the image set $\phi(J)$ of $\phi$ is a *selection from A*.

The second point basically says that a selection from $A$ is a set that contains at most one element from each set in $A$. The reason we can't just say exactly that is because, for instance, what if we have the menu $A=(\{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\})$? Then $\{1, 2\}$ should be a selection from it, but does it really contain at most one element from each set in $A$? You could say that it contains two elements from $A_1$ and none from $A_2$. By involving an explicit function $\phi$ that tells you exactly where each element in the selection came from, you can side-step this ambiguity. We make $\phi$ a function over a subset $J$ of the indexing set $I$ so that we can allow for selections that ignore certain of the sets in $A$.

Now, if $A$ is a finite menu and each $A_i$ is finite, *and if the members of $A$ are pairwise disjoint*, then I believe the number of possible selections from $A$ is $$\prod_{i\in I}(|A_i|+1)$$

My reasoning for this is as follows. Suppose you have to make $n$ choices, and for each choice you have $c_n$ options. How many possible configurations of choices could you make? The answer is obviously $\prod c_i$. When constructing any selection from a menu $A$, you have to make one choice for each $A_i$ - which element you choose from it. You have $|A_i|+1$ options for this choice - $|A_i|$ elements to choose from, with one extra option since you can also choose to not take anything from $A_i$.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me understand more, I will look this over. (Just a small note - I didn't say "formalize", rather "formularize," as in derive a formula for.)

Comment: Wow, the formula works for the tests I tried! That's terrific! Math is incredible. I will need some time to understand your explanation, having a limited mathematical background. How do you arrive at the formula?

Comment: @groovy If you understand what you're trying to do, then you don't need my formal definition, except in so far as it's needed to understand the notations in the formula at the bottom. I'll edit in my reasoning for the formula.